# How to parse EDIFACT file data using apache spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, edi, edifact

Can someone suggest me how to parse EDIFACT format data using Apache spark ?

i have a requirement as every day EDIFACT data will be written to aws s3 bucket. i am trying to find a best way to convert this data to structured format using Apache spark.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have your invoices in EDIFACT format you can read each one of them as one String per Invoice using RDD´s. Then you will have a RDD[String] which represents the distributed invoice collection. Take  a look to https://github.com/CenPC434/java-tools with this you can convert the EDIFACT strings to XML. This repo https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml shows how to use XML format as input source to create Dataframes and perform multiples queries, aggregation... Etc.